# How can I look up a DNS MX record for a given server in Java?

Tags: java, dns, smtp, mx-record

Anybody knows how to get MX address (from for example gmail.com) in java using standard libraries? Or do I need to download external one?

I'm using netbeans if it can be helpful (if it provides something for this).

Comment: Does the solution need to be platform independent, and if not, which platform will it run on?

Comment: You can look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261995/finding-smtp-host-and-port-knowing-the-e-mail-address-using-java-api

Answer (score 15):

I was also searching for standart lib for this in java. Unsuccessful.

Then I have used [dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/).

```
private Record[] lookupMxRecords(final String domainPart) throw TextParseException
{
    final Lookup dnsLookup = new Lookup(domainPart, Type.MX);
    return dnsLookup.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Main.java

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
        env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns://8.8.8.8/");
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        Attributes attrsl = ctx.getAttributes("google.com", new String[] {"MX"});
        Attribute attr = attrsl.get("MX");
        if (attr != null) {
            System.out.println("MX records:");
            for (Enumeration vals = attr.getAll(); vals.hasMoreElements();) {
                System.out.println(vals.nextElement());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

issues

```
$ javac Main.java && java Main
MX records:
20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 aspmx.l.google.com.
40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```