# Determine Mail Settings from Domain

Tags: java, email, web, smtp

I'm currently writing a simple Java application that will allow the user to send and receive email. When the application starts, it prompts the user to log in in the following format:

username@provider.com

passwd

Currently I have the field split so that provider.com is placed in its own string. Is there any way I can use the java mail api or something else to retrieve the settings for "provider.com?" I'm looking to get back strings such as "smtp.gmail.com" when the user has a gmail account and so-forth. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: To clarify what I am after...

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // I want to get this (smtp.gmail.com)
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); // And this (465)
// from the user entered "gmail.com" or "live.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this after some more searching: [Finding SMTP host and port knowing the e-mail address using JAVA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261995/finding-smtp-host-and-port-knowing-the-e-mail-address-using-java-api)

It seems there is no predictable way to do this. Very disappointing.